# Convert matrix product to nx.Graph

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I have a dataframe like this

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : [1,1,0,0], 'b': [0,1,1,0], 'c': [0,0,1,1]})
```

I get a matrix product

```
df.T.dot(df)

   a  b  c
a  2  1  0
b  1  2  1
c  0  1  2
```

And I want to get `nx.Graph` and then to `nx.draw_networkx`.

```
G.add_node('a', weight = 2 ) # 2 means sum of 'a'
....................
G.add_edge('a','b',range=1) # 1 means cell's value at the intersection
................
```

Of course I can do it by hand as above, but in a real dataset more data. Is there more easy way to convert matrix product to `nx.Graph`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loops! If I understand you correctly, the following should work,

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 1, 1]})

product = df.T.dot(df)

graph = nx.Graph()

for column in df.columns:
    graph.add_node(column, weight=product[column][column])

for row_label, values in product.iterrows():
    for column_label, value in values.iteritems():
        if row_label != column_label:
            graph.add_edge(row_label, column_label, range=value)

nx.draw_networkx(graph)
plt.show()
```

Which yields,

[image: Example graph]

Comment: that's fantastic)

Answer (score 1):

Another option, without loops, is to use pandas dataframe reshaping and networkx 2.0 with pandas integration methods:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 0, 0], 'b': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'c': [0, 0, 1, 1]})

product = df.T.dot(df)

graph = nx.Graph()

dfG = product.stack().rename('value').rename_axis(['source','target']).reset_index()

G = nx.Graph()

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(dfG.query('source != target'), 'source', 'target', 'value', G)

attr_dict = dfG.query('source == target').set_index('source')['value'].to_dict()
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attr_dict,'weight')

nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I expected that there was a standard tool.
because the task would seem very popular